# java.lang.InstantiationError: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBDataSource

Tags: eclipse, apache-axis, wso2-as, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to develop a web app using eclipse IDE and Apache Tomcat (7). When I deploy the .WAR file on wso2 AS and open the url, I get this error every time inspite of using the same versions of axis2 for building and generating the code. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
java.lang.InstantiationError: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBDataSource
    org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub.Authenticate.getOMElement(Authenticate.java:126)
    org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub.RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.toEnvelope(RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.java:9387)
    org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub.RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.authenticate(RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.java:4030)
    org.wso2.sample.LoginServlet.authenticate(LoginServlet.java:77)
    org.wso2.sample.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:38)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.wso2.sample.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:42)
```